# Fazer click automático a cada 10 segundos

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho um carousel no site, e quero que a cada dez segundos, ele seja executado, como se o visitante tivesse clicado no botão para efetuar esse processo.

Esse é o site http://www.clinicafelipemeletti.com.br/

Aqui está todo o JS do plugin (WP Carousel Posts) https://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/c3dL9tzj/

E aqui, a inclusão que eu fiz nesse JS

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementsByClassName("owl-dot").click();
}, 10000);
```

Não está funcionando. Gostaria de saber porque.

Answer (score 4):

Uma sugestão:
Talvez seja legal você dar uma olhada no carrossel do Bootstrap, caso não conheça:
[Carrossel com Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

Bom, mas se você precisa dessa forma o funcionamento do site, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
var runCarousel = function (carousel, index, timeout) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    carousel[index].click();
    }, index*timeout);
}
```

Essa função fará com que o carrossel(carousel) selecionado "rode" o carrossel com a diferença de tempo (timeout) que você quer.

Um exemplo de uso da função seria assim:

```
var carousel = document.getElementsByClassName("owl-dot");

for (var i = 0; i < carousel.length; i++) {
    runCarousel(carousel, i, 2000)
}
```

Isto fará com que o carrossel (com  botões de classe "owl-dot") rodem de 2 em 2 segundos!

Espero ter ajudado,

Giulio~

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica do Bootstrap. Eu não vou usar agora, pois esse site não foi eu quem desenvolveu. Por isso estou com dificuldades para resolver isso.
O código que você me passou, será que funciona se eu colocar nesse arquivo JS?
http://www.clinicafelipemeletti.com.br/wp-content/plugins/wp-posts-carousel/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.js?ver=2.0.0
Se sim, aonde seria o ideal?

Comment: Felipe, esse código realmente está bem grande. Parece até que existem funções lá que vão fazer girar o carrossel... Mas, considerando que você só precisa da solução rápida do problema, eu colocaria como uma função assíncrona em loop infinito fora do carrossel. Acredito que essa não seja a melhor solução, mas já vai resolver seu problema de forma rápida!

Answer (score 1):

Estive a dar uma olhada no site. Se se estiver a a traballar no show de fotos da home page:

jquery:

```
var slideNum = 0;
setInterval(function() {
   jQuery('a.nivo-control').removeClass('active');
   jQuery('a.nivo-control[rel="' +slideNum+ '"]').click();
   jQuery('a.nivo-control[rel="' +slideNum+ '"]').addClass('active');
   slideNum += 1;
   if(slideNum >= jQuery('a.nivo-control').length) {
       slideNum = 0;
   }
}, 10000);
```